# how to access to subproperties with jpa metamodel in where clause

Tags: jpa, properties, criteria, metamodel

I have a two entities with relation between they are.

```
public class Client implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 3, max = 25)
private String firstName;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 3, max = 25)
private String lastName;

private String login;

private String password;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "client")
private List<Project> projects;
}
```

and

```
public class Project implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4762714047114442539L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

private String name;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date startDate;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn
private Client client;
}
```

I want to made a query using jpametamodel and Criteria API. Like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Project> q = cb.createQuery(Project.class);
Root<Project> projects = q.from(Project.class);
q.where(cb.equal(projects.get(Project_.client), clientId));
```

Problem for me that i don't know how to get access to "id" property of Client in this string:

```
q.where(cb.equal(projects.get(Project_.client), clientId));
```

i want to get something like

```
q.where(cb.equal(projects.get("client.id"), clientId));
```

but with jpametamodel. It is possible? :)

Comment: Ok the string :
    q.where(cb.equal(projects.get("client.id"), clientId));
lead to error. And now i know that the string:
    q.where(cb.equal(projects.get(Project_.client), clientId));
make exactly what i want. (make a restriction on client id)
But now i want to know  how to do chain references on subproperties using jpametamodel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried something like this?

```
projects.get(Project_.client).get(Client_.id);
```